# What are the "extra" 32 bytes on the Windows stack?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, callstack, stack-frame

I'm learning assembly on Windows and trying to figure out what the values on the stack are.
The [Visual C++ documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-usage?view=vs-2019)
says that the values above RSP are:

- Allocated space
- Saved RBP
- Return address
- Registers home (RCX, RDX, R8, R9)
- Function parameters

The problem is that there are 32 extra bytes in the stack not mentioned in the documentation.

[image]

In the [memory snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XucUy.png) RSP starts at 0x0000000000DAF5E0. The colored boxes are:

- Yellow: two 64 bits variables with value 9
- White: saved old RBP + return address
- Blue: function parameters
- Green: registers home
- Red: ?

What could those bytes in red be?

MASM source code built with VS2019, MASM64 and running in x64 debug mode.

C++ flags: /JMC /permissive- /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pch" /diagnostics:column

```
.code

; int64_t StackFrameDemo_(int8_t a, int16_t b, int32_t c, int64_t d, int8_t e, int16_t f, int32_t g, int64_t h)
StackFrameDemo_ proc frame

; prolog
push rbp
.pushreg rbp

; allocate 16 bytes on the stack
sub rsp, 16
.allocstack 16
.endprolog

; save registers to register home
mov qword ptr [rbp+8], rcx
mov qword ptr [rbp+16], rdx
mov qword ptr [rbp+24], r8
mov qword ptr [rbp+32], r9

; save the two variables
mov rax, 9
mov [rsp], rax
mov [rsp+type qword], rax

nop ; set the break point here to view memory

; epilog
add rsp, 16 ; release local stack space
pop rbp     ; restore caller's rbp register

ret

StackFrameDemo_ endp

end
```

Comment: I've not read your question but are you talking about the space reserved for spilling the argument registers? IIRC was called something like "homing/shadow space/zone". It is well documented indeed.

Comment: Your picture doesn't correspond to your description at all. x86-stacks grow *downwards*. Also, don't write to wild pointers, that's a terrible idea.

Comment: @EOF: I'm pretty sure this code wasn't *intentionally* writing through a wild pointer (RBP); that's unnoticed the bug that led to confusion.  Also note that the description starts with things that would be at the lowest address, so it's describing it in increasing-address order, opposite of growth order.  I think that's how the diagram is drawn?  I didn't check super carefully after noticing the missing RBP init; I assumed that was the only issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to do `mov rbp, rsp` (after `push rbp`) to make RBP a frame pointer into *your* stack frame.

**Your "home space" aka shadow space *is* 32 bytes above your return address, you're just not using it.**  (And instead violating the calling convention by storing relative to some register that could have any value.  In this case your caller was probably also using RBP for a legacy frame pointer, so you're probably just stepping on your caller's home space.)

---

Note that `0xCC` is the value MSVC debug mode uses to poison the stack, helping detect reads of uninitialized memory.  (And if you accidentally execute memory with those contents, it's the x86 `int3` debug breakpoint instruction.)

---

And BTW, when you're using RBP as a traditional frame pointer, `mov rsp, rbp` / `pop rbp` / `ret` is more efficient than `add rsp, 16` / `pop rbp`.  Slightly smaller code-size, and some CPUs do mov-elimination to avoid needing an execution unit for `mov`.  This would have broken more noisily for you, like maybe returning from your caller's return address, which you might have noticed when single-stepping!

(`leave` = mov/pop, so you can use that for even smaller code-size.  It's ok for performance, unlike `enter`; GCC uses `leave` in functions with a frame pointer that end with RSP not already pointing at the saved RBP.  Some other compilers prefer mov/pop.  But compilers usually only use `add rsp, n` when they weren't using a frame pointer at all.)

Frame pointers are optional, and are not a required part of stack-frame layout.  Directives like `.allocstack 16` create the metadata that makes stack unwinding possible without the traditional linked list of frame pointers.

Comment: Peter, the _mov rbp, rsp_ did the trick, the memory layout makes sense now!  I had to add 8 bytes on the _mov qword ptr [rbp+8]_ instructions as they were overwriting the return value; rsp, before allocating the 16 bytes starts before the pushed rbp value, hence +8 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: @gfurtadoalmeida: oh yes, your offsets from RBP to the home space were wrong, too.  That's the correct fix, I just hadn't noticed that other bug.  With a traditional frame pointer, the first stack slot above the return address is 2 slots above the frame pointer (which points to the saved RBP).

Comment: Peter, do you have any link or book suggestion where I coud learn more about stack operations and rbp, rsp relationship?

Comment: @gfurtadoalmeida: Most of the duplicate links in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60861381) are relevant. (32-bit code has 4-byte instead of 8-byte stack slots).  I found them with `site:stackoverflow.com esp ebp difference`.  I'd recommend looking at optimized compiler output for how compilers use the stack, e.g. only setting up a legacy stack pointer in functions that use `alloca()` or variable-length arrays, or that over-align the stack.  Or in unoptimized code how they reserve space for locals, but you're already doing that in your function.